# mechanics of django WSGI POST object

Tags: python, django

I have a django form with POST method in index.html, with multi-checkboxes enabled for the field "preferences".

**in Views.py, I have the following code:**

```
preferences = request.POST
print(preferences)
preferences = request.POST.get("preferences")
print(preferences)
```

**Output in console**:

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['xyz'], 'preferences': ['drink', 'food'], 'submit': ['submit']}>
```

food

**why does the output only select the latter element ("food") instead of ['drink','food']?**

**Also, please help me understand how to achieve the output of all preferences.**

thank you!

Comment: All explained in: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict

Answer (score 0):

You can access preferences by using **getlist()**

As you are getting preferences in list so,you can access it in views 
like,

preference_list = request.POST.getlist("preferences")

you can get reference on this in below link
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict